# Python script placed in /usr/bin not saving data in sqlite db

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, ubuntu-18.04, shebang

I wrote a program which gets username and password from the user and creates a table in an SQLite DB then sends those data through a connection to DB.

It was working fine until I added the shebang in my code, then I made it executable(chmod +x) and after all, I put that file into /usr/bin so that I could use it anywhere in the terminal. now it runs but it doesn't work (it doesn't add data to DB).

here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
__author__ = "Taha Jalili"
__license__ = "GPL"
__version__ = "1.0.0"
__email__ = "tahajalili@gmail.com"

import sys
import sqlite3
from sqlite3 import *
import inquirer

SQL_CREATE_STATEMENT = '''CREATE TABLE password
             (id integer PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,username text, password text, source text)'''
SQL_INSERT_STATEMENT = '''INSERT INTO password (username, password, source)VALUES(?,?,?)'''

DATABASE_PATH = '/home/taha/lessons/projects/passStorage/passDB.db'


def create_connection(db_file):
    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
        return conn
        print('Connection created.')
    except Error as e:
        return e

# def create_table(connection, sql_commands):
#   c = connection.cursor()
#   c.execute(sql_commands)
#   print('=> Table created.')

def get_input():
    USERNAME = input('username: ')
    PASSWORD = input('password: ')
    SOURCE = input('source: ')
    return USERNAME,PASSWORD,SOURCE

def insert_date(connection,data):
    try:
        c = connection.cursor()
        c.execute(SQL_INSERT_STATEMENT, data)
        print('=> Data insertion done.')
    except Error as e:
        return e

def show_info(connection):
    c = connection.cursor()
    info = c.execute('SELECT * FROM password ORDER BY id')
    print('YOUR PASSWORDS'.center(45,'-'))
    print('(id, username, password, source)')
    for row in info:
        print(row,'')
    print('\n')

def ask_again():
    user_choice = input("Wish to continue? Y/N ")
    if user_choice == 'y' or user_choice == 'Y':
        main()
    elif user_choice == 'n' or user_choice == 'N':
        print("==> BYE <==")
        sys.exit(0)

def main():
    conn = create_connection(DATABASE_PATH)
    # create_table(conn, SQL_CREATE_STATEMENT)

    questions = [
        inquirer.List(
                'job',
                message = 'What should I do?',
                choices=['Add data','Show saved data.']
            ),
        ]
    answers = inquirer.prompt(questions)

    if answers['job'] == 'Add data':
        conn2 = create_connection(DATABASE_PATH)
        insert_date(conn2,get_input())
    elif answers['job'] == 'Show saved data.':
        show_info(conn)

    ask_again() 
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: How do you run it?

Comment: Cannot explain how it worked "before", because commit never executes.

Comment: @MarkSetchell by just typing storage.py in terminal cause I put the file in /usr/bin

Comment: @DinoCoderSaurus I test it and it works fine(I meant the commit func.)

Comment: The commit will only execute if `user_choice` in `ask_again` is _not_ y,n,Y or N. If user types y|Y, `main()` will execute and no commit. If user types n|N, program exits and no commit. If user types anything else (a for instance), commit (and close) will execute.